# basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')") erro while running next js project

Tags: reactjs, next.js, yarn-v2

I'm trying to run a next js project with yarn and when I type `yarn dev` it shows me this error:

```
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
      ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
   at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:77:18)
   at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1288:20)
   at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1340:27)
   at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
   at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
   at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
   at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] 
   (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
   at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49
```